# Is there a on-the-fly drupal image resizer?

Tags: php, drupal

Is there an image resizer in Drupal or in a Drupal module that would let you do something like:

```
theme_image_resize($source, $heightx$width, $options);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Drupal 7 comes with image styles, which lets you create presets that include scaling, cropping, and a host of other image manipulation actions. You can resize any image programmatically using [`theme_image_style()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--image--image.module/function/theme_image_style/7):

```
$options = array(
  'style_name' => 'small', // Machine name of style defined in Admin UI or image_style_save()
  'path' => 'public://myimage.png',
  'alt' => t('resized image'),
  'title' => t('resized image'),
  'attributes' => array(
    'class' => array('awesome', 'inset', 'resized'),
    'rel' => 'lightbox',
  ),
);
$image_html = theme('image_style', $options);
```

The Drupal 6 equivalent is to use the [ImageCache](http://drupal.org/project/imagecache), which has a similar API and workflow.

Answer (score 3):

As the name said, **ImageCache** will cache the resized image, so it's not anymore resized on-the-fly in the next times.

ImageCache was ported and included in Drupal 7's core, so [theme_image_style()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!image!image.module/function/theme_image_style/7) is the equivalent of it.

These "efficient wrappers" are probably what you are looking for. But **if you want only the resize function**, then have a look to image.inc in Drupal core, which contains [image_resize()[2](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--image.inc/function/image_resize/6).

This Drupal 6 function will call to the Image Toolkit you have enabled (G2 or Imagemagick) in your Drupal site.

In case of Drupal 6, [ImageAPI](http://drupal.org/project/imageapi) has really similar functions but more efficient way of handling images, and has been included in Drupal 7's core, so pay attention to the differences in the arguments of [image_resize()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!image.inc/function/image_resize/7) in Drupal 7.

Answer (score 2):

There is module for that. It is called http://drupal.org/project/image_resize_filter. You need to make new text filter format, add only Image resize filter, note filter machine name. Then in code apply filter to html string of your image tag using `check_markup()`. Filter wil look for width and/or height tag to resize image and save resized in your file system for future use.